# Como es posible evitar estos errores en angular? Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

lo que pasa es que tengo el siguiente problema con mi código de angular y me gustaría saber como hacerlo mejor o arreglar estos errores. Tengo un login que lo que hace es guardar el token de autenticación en el localstorage, al igual que el usuario, rol y correo. Lo que busco con esto es que al iniciar sesion, me salga una alerta de bienvenida con el nombre y el rol, hasta ahora todo normal, funciona muy bien hasta ahi, pero el problema es que al hacer eso, salen demasiados errores, debido a que quiero poner el nombre y el rol en el navbar. Son (29) errores de lo mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle F5 a la página pues los errores desaparecen y pues ya en la página de inicio me sale el nombre de usuario y su rol en el navbar, me gustaría saber como evitar estos errores, otro problema que se me presenta es que al cerrar sesión, los datos se eliminan del localstorage, pero al volver a iniciar sesión con un usuario nuevo, al no darle f5 a la página, sigue saliendo el mismo usuario que logeado anteriormente.

Este es mi codigo al iniciar sesion

```
    signIn() {
    this.authService.signIn(this.user).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        const datosUser = {
          id: res.datos._id,
          email: res.datos.email,
          nombre_usuario: res.datos.nombre_usuario,
          rol: res.datos.rol,
        };
        this.authService.setToken(res.token);
        //localStorage.setItem("token", res.token);
        this.authService.setUser(datosUser);
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
        //localStorage.setItem("datos", JSON.stringify(datosUser));
        Swal.fire(
          "Bienvenido " + res.datos.nombre_usuario,
          "Tu Rol es: " + res.datos.rol,
          "success"
        );

      },
      (err) => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Error",
          text:
            "No se ha podido iniciar sesion, verifique su correo y contraseña",
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Aqui estan los set's

```
setToken(token) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
  }

  setUser(user) {
    localStorage.setItem("datos", JSON.stringify(user));
  }
```

Luego trato de traer esos datos a app-component.html

```
export class AppComponent {
  user: any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datos"));
  }
}
```

Y en el HTML tengo esto

```
    <li>
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active">{{user.nombre_usuario}}</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-link">
                Rol: {{user.rol}}
   </li>
```

**Estado actual del error:**

Logre que al iniciar sesión la página carga el nombre y el usuario correcto sin mostrar ningún error, al igual que cuando se cierra sesión y se vuelve abrir. Resulta que ahora el nuevo problema es que cuando doy F5, otra vez todo se daña y es como si nada estuviese definido. Este es el código que tengo actualmente.

APPCOMPONENT:

```
public static updateUserStatus: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  user: any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

      AppComponent.updateUserStatus.subscribe((res) => {
        this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datos"));
      });

  }
```

Servicio:

```
signIn(user): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.URL + "/signin", user)
      .pipe(map((res) => res));
  }
```

Componente login:

```
signUp(form: NgForm) {
    return this.authService.signUp(this.user).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.authService.setUser(res.datos);
        this.authService.setToken(res.token);
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
        AppComponent.updateUserStatus.next(true);
        Swal.fire(
          "Bienvenido " + res.datos.nombre_usuario,
          "Tu Rol es: " + res.datos.rol,
          "success"
        );
      },
      (err) => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Error",
          text:
            "No se ha podido iniciar sesion, verifique su correo y contraseña",
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Controlador login:

```
userController.logInUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  const user = await model_user.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(409).send("El correo no existe");
  } else {
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (match) {
      const datos = {
        email: user.email,
        nombre_usuario: user.name,
        rol: user.rol,
      };
      const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, secretKey, {
        expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24, // expires in 24 hours
      });
      return res.status(200).json({ datos, token });
    } else {
      return res.status(409).send("Contraseña erronea");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Como side note, yo te recomendaría por seguridad no almacenar el token en local storage.

Comment: Estaría bien saber qué hace `this.authService.signIn(this.user)` y que devuelve realmente.

Comment: Hola, en la edición de la pregunta mostré que hace signIn,  en cuanto al controlador, no sé si sirva, lo colocare en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando seteas un suscribe tienes esta sintaxis:

```
servicio().suscribe(datos => metodo(datos), 
                    error => manejoError(error), 
                    completado => metodoCuandoElSuscribeTermine()
)
```

Si quieres manejar errores en el suscribe debes implementar tu metodo que controla errores, despues del primer metodo que implementas al suscribe.
Tambien los datos del usuario te recomiendo guardarlo en un subject en tu servicio y lo vas a poder consumir desde cualquier componente.
En cuanto al token te recomiendo guardarlo en las cookies porque puedes setearle un tiempo de caducidad

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, acabe de editar mi pregunta y mostré completamente el signin(), gracias por tus recomendaciones, soy nuevo en angular, se me olvido aclararlo, podrías explicarme como es lo del subject?

Comment: Otra pregunta que se me acabo de ocurrir, lo recomendable seria poner el navigate() en la parte de completado? cuando el subscribe termine y guarde los datos, me imagino

Comment: Claro los observable, subject, etc. son funcionalidades de rxjs un ejemplo de como implementarlo en tu proyecto seria asi 
`private datosUsuario$ = new Subject<UsuarioModel[]>();
  usuarios:UsuarioModel[] =[]
  obtenerUsuarioGuardado(): Observable<UsuarioModel[]>{
    return this.datosUsuario$.asObservable();
  }
  establecerUsuario(usuario:UsuarioModel){
    this.usuarios=[]
    this.usuarios.push(usuario)
    this.datosUsuario$.next(this.usuarios) 
  }
  limpiarUsuarios(){
    this.usuarios=[]
    this.datosUsuario$.next(this.usuarios) 
  }`

Comment: No porque si da error igual te va a redirigir al home, aqui tienes un ejemplo de la documentacion de angular 
`const myObservable = of(1, 2, 3);

// Create observer object
const myObserver = {
  next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
};`

Comment: Oye amigo, genial, muchas gracias la verdad, no sabia sobre los subject y acabo de arreglar mi problema <3

Comment: Por cierto, logre solucionar que al principio cuando iniciara sesión no salieran todos los errores de usuario y rol indefinido, ya ahora cuando inicio sesión, carga normal y aun si cierro sesión y elijo otro usuario, aparece el usuario correcto, el problema que tengo ahora y que apenas me di cuenta después de ver unas cosas es que al darle F5, otra vez manda error de usuario indefinido muchas veces. Editare mi pregunta con el código actual

Comment: El error aparece cuando estas logueado ??? sigues guardando los datos del usuario en el local storage ???. Se me ocurre que el error te da en  la funcion que realizas en el ngOnInit

Comment: Posiblemente el error que tienes es que al recargar la pagina, pierdes el usuario en memoria (en tu servicio). Puedes crear un `guard.ts` en tus rutas que compruebe si los datos estan en el `localstorage`, si estan, haces de nuevo un `localstorage.getItem('tuItem ') as Usuario`

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

**AppComponent**: Lee únicamente los datos 1 vez, en onInit, y lo lee del local storage.

El login se realiza después, y se almacena todo en localStorage (que es durable pese al F5), por eso al darle a F5 ves al usuario.

Lo que yo te recomendaría sería tener un sito claro donde guardas el "estado", al menos parcial, que tiene tu user y token. Llamemosle por ejemplo "AuthStateService"

por ejemplo:
**AuthStateService**
Puedes añadir métodos para setear el user, incluso leerlo del localStorage si queires desde el constructor, pero no te lo recomiendo.

```
@Injectable
export class AuthStateService {
  public user$: Observable<User>;
  private userSubject$: ReplaySubject<User>;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.user$ = userSubject$.asObservable();
    this.userSubject$ = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  }

  public signIn(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.authService.signIn({ email, password })
    .pipe(tap(user => { this.user = user; });
  }
}
```

**AppComponent**

Recibira el user únicamente cuando alguien haga login, sino, será null. Al hacer F5 será null.

```
@Component({
 ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public user: User = null;

  private subscriptions = new Subscription();

  constructor(private authStateService: AuthStateService) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.authStateService.user$.subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
      })
    );
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Y en algún lugar...

```
  this.authStateService.signIn(email, password)
  .subscribe(user => {
    ...
   });
```